# Is there a good reason for lstlistings code to look so ugly by default?

Tags: listings, typography

I always thought the purpose of LaTeX was to make it easy to create *beautiful* documents. Yet every time I see one of those `lstlistings` I can't help but wince at the mutilated kerning. Take for example this simple snippet taken from the `\tikzmark` documentation:

[image: What's happening here?]

Why are the two highlighted uses of the word *use* typeset so differently? It's not monospace and not proportional but something... else. I added vertical lines between the top characters to showcase the wacky alignment.

This is also the reason I normally don't use that package at all and resort to `tabular`s with `\ttfamily` or `verbatim` environments.

So, why does it do this? Why make ugly the default and make people search for a way to make it look good (which nobody seems to be bothered with, judging from the amount of papers and lecture notes containing ugly listings), instead of making it look nice by default? Is there a good technical or typographic reason to do it this way instead of using a proper monospace font—which should always be present—or at least properly using the proportional font?

Are there other packages that do a better job at listing actual program code (i.e. not algorithms in pseudocode) by default?

There have been other questions about making `lstlisting`s look better, like [How can I make lstlisting look exactly like verbatim?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172702/how-can-i-make-lstlisting-look-exactly-like-verbatim) or [lstlisting, tt fonts, and alignment.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20486/lstlisting-tt-fonts-and-alignment), so that is not really the topic here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess only the creator of the package can answer the question.

Comment: To answer what "other packages" there might be, it might help if you also provide what features are essential for your application.  For example, keyword highlighting, etc.

Comment: re the style, there's some history in the `listings` package documentation, in section 2.10.  but it doesn't say "why".

Comment: adding `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible}` is easy enough. Why the default is as it is is pure speculation as long as we can't ask the original author. IMHO there are no better packages than `listings` when it comes to typesetting code (even with all the flaws it might have) (well, `minted` maybe...) but this is again speculation and opinion-based. There is no good answer to this question so IMHO it should be closed.

Comment: The same question I asked myself when I discovered `listings`. As @cgnieder says, it's easy to select the style you want, but I also wonder when would one ever prefer the default style you show in the image!

Comment: No, there's no good reason other than “the original author of `listings` liked it”. Whether it's good or bad is a matter of opinion; the package easily allows to change the setup.

Comment: Unfortunately the original author, Carsten Heinz, abandoned the work on `listings` some years ago. Does anybody know why?

Comment: @morbusg Well, someone might know what is what Listings try to do “intelligently” which is something that seems no one understand. I see a close-vote as primarily opinion based, I don't think it's. Because no one has ever said what is it that listings try to do. In any case I think it might be Off Topic here…

Comment: Add `[columns=fullflexible]` to the listing environment to see the difference which also tells you why it is as such. This is something related to the terminal input emulation fun but I can't make an example now. The explanation is in the manual somewhere

Comment: I think that this question is quite pertinent even if it is written as an opinionated question on "look and feel". It could be easily rewritten as "how can one get monospace typesetting in listings ... and that is an important question. (personally I think you get too hooked up on throwing out questions because they use the words "ugly" etc. :-)

Comment: I also think it should be reopened. While my _argument_ is clearly an opinion, asking for a technical reason why this is so (if one exists) is _not_ opinionated. If anyone who knows such a reason comes across this question, they should be allowed to answer.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I disagree in this case: the question says »There have been other questions about making lstlistings look better [...] so that is not really the topic here.«. If it were rewritten it'd probably be closed as duplicate of the mentioned other question.

Comment: @cgnieder can accept that position didn't really read to the bottom it seems.

Comment: As we talk about opinions here I just want to say that I for instance like the output of listings package. I am not an expert latex user so to have seen a lot of other packages but even without customization I don't find it ugly (even thought I personally make customizations while using it). I don't want someone to mistake what I say here and take it for more than a simple "rookie" opinion!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(Actual answer: use `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}`)

---

### Joke answer (Do *not* do that!)

I'll fix that for you. Here is a custom package called `fritzlistings`, built on top of `listings`, that uses a typewriter font by default.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{fritzlistings}%
 [2014/09/08 v0.1 Fritz's listings]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{listings}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\RequirePackage{listings}
\lst@Key{basicstyle}\ttfamily{\def\lst@basicstyle{#1}}
\endinput
```

There. Happy now? `:p`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fritzlistings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

### More seriously...

> I can't help but wince at the mutilated kerning. [...] This is also the reason I normally don't use that package at all and resort to tabulars with `\ttfamily` or `verbatim` environments.

If you're typesetting source code, what would be the advantage of using a `tabular` environment with `\ttfamily` versus using an `lstlisting` environment? I can't think of any. Besides, you can configure `listings` to replicate the look of a `verbatim` environment (as shown in [How can I make lstlisting look exactly like verbatim?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172702/how-can-i-make-lstlisting-look-exactly-like-verbatim)), but with the nonnegligible benefit of automatic line breaking.

> Why make ugly the default and make people search for a way to make it look good (which nobody seems to be bothered with, judging from the amount of papers and lecture notes containing ugly listings), instead of making it look by default?

I agree with you that the output of `listings` is basic and arguably ugly, but beauty is in the eye of the beholder. What you may find beautiful, others may find ugly as f**k. I think that Carsten Heinz, the author of `listings`, simply didn't want to impose any particular style on the user. In particular, you'll notice that language definitions in `lstdvrs.dtx` are just that: language definitions; keys such as `keywordstyle` are not used in those language definitions.

The package provides many ways of customizing the look of the output. Use them to suit your needs (I typically save my favourite styles in a custom LaTeX package), and spread the word; that will do more to improve the current state of affair than a rant.

> Is there a good, technical or typographic reason to do it this way instead of using a proper monospace font (that should always be present) or at least properly using the proportional font?

I agree with you that the default `columns=fixed` and `cmr` don't go well together. Either

- either `columns=fixed` and `cmtt`,
- or  `columns=flexible` (or `fullflexible`) and `cmr`,

would have made more sense to me, although [others would disagree about that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172702/how-can-i-make-lstlisting-look-exactly-like-verbatim/172705#comment398881_172705). So why is that the default? Who knows... All I can gather from `listings.dtx` is that the `basicstyle` key (introduced in v0.18) predates the `columns` key (v1.0). I don't have access to the full development history of the package, so I can only speculate.

My theory is that `listings`' default is what it is for historical reasons. I'm guessing that `listings` originally didn't tamper with the kerning at all before the inception of the `columns` key in v1.0; before that, `cmr` would have been an acceptable choice of font for listings. Then v1.0 came, but perhaps Carsten thought changing the default font to `cmtt` at that stage would have upset existing `listings` users, and he decided to stick to `cmr`.

Of course, only Carsten Heinz (or perhaps one of the maintainers, active or retired) could provide a conclusive rationale for this choice.

> Are there other packages that do a better job at listing actual program code (not algorithms in pseudocode) by default?

Pygments-based packages, such as `minted`, `verbments`, and `pythontex`, have some advantages over listings, thanks to Python; in particular,

- superior lexing/scanning capabilities,
- full Unicode support,

come to mind. However, in terms of customisation *from within* LaTeX (& friends) documents, `listings` wins; no question about that. At least, that's the case at the moment; `minted` may end up catching up with `listings`, in this respect.

Comment: Better use `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}`, it's the publicly documented command AFAIK.

Comment: @marczellm That was a joke, obviously...

Comment: Thanks for the very elaborate (and indeed helpful) answer. I guess this is as close as we can get, so I'll accept it.

Comment: Altough it answers in a way the question, I still wonder what is it that `listings` does “intelligently” with those spaces, does anyone know what does it do? I'm talking only about `columns=fixed`.

Comment: Maybe it is trying to equalize the space between each pair of letters on each individual line. Thus, a sequence of narrow letters like l or i will occupy less space than a sequence of wide letters like W and G

Comment: @Fritz -- as i see it, `listings` is trying to make letters in a proportional font align so that a code listing will have reliable columnar alignment; this can be important in viewing code that is *supposed* to be aligned from line to line where horizontal position matters.  (but it *does* look unattractive, and i personally prefer a reasonably designed monospace font for the purpose.)

Comment: *"That was a joke, obviously... "* sorry, but I did not find that too obvious, despite the following *"More seriously..."* line. Given that this is a long-term Q&A site and your answer is the accepted answer, I foresee new `listings` users adopting your solution.

Comment: @Daniel I'll edit my answer to make it clear that I was joking.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You mean similar to [elastic tabstops](http://nickgravgaard.com/elastictabstops/)? Maybe my example is bad because it contains no spaces on which to align things. But whatever it does, I can't make sense of why it would typeset the two uses of the word `use` in my example so differently.

Comment: Thanks, almost perfect :-) I would just add the "official solution", as suggested by @marczellm, somewhere below the joke, so that users just looking for a simple fix to the problem can find it.

Comment: @Fritz -- you're correct, and thanks for calling me on it.  what i see, now that i look more closely, is that the input is parsed into words, a horizontal space is allotted for each word (that appears ultimately to equate to the space needed for presentation of the monospace form), and within that space the word is letterspaced evenly.  you're quite correct -- the two lines in the example you show *don't* have letter-by-letter alignment.